# dm-crypt with LUKS - aes kernel module

Tags: kernel, encryption, luks

[Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage) says that an aes kernel module needs to be enabled for using aes and dm-crypt with LUKS but when I run `modprobe aes` as the documentation says to, I get `ERROR: could not insert 'padlock_aes': No such device`. The documentation considers this error saying that it can be a sign that my system "does not have a hardware cryptographic device." But I have a modern i7 CPU and `grep aes /proc/cpuinfo` reveals the aes flag.

If I ignore the kernel module command and continue along with cryptsetup everything seems to work correctly. This is even with ignoring the Ubuntu documentation's remedy for the error of `alias aes aes_generic`.

In comparison. The Arch Linux [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_Encryption_with_LUKS) on performing the same task does not include the kernel module loading step (see under the heading "Formatting LUKS Partitions").

Given that cryptsetup works even if I throw the Ubuntu documentation's advice to the wind and that the Arch guide doesn't even mention what the Ubuntu documentation did I am getting the feeling that perhaps the aes module is preloaded in newer kernels perhaps?

I expect that I will have hardware level aes support with the hardware that I own.

Answer (score 5):

From the ubuntu guide you referenced:

> If the following error messages appear when loading sha256 and aes:

```
sudo modprobe sha256
WARNING: Error inserting padlock_sha (/lib/modules/2.6.24-21-generic/kernel/drivers/crypto/padlock-sha.ko): No such device

sudo modprobe aes
WARNING: Error inserting padlock_aes (/lib/modules/2.6.24-21-generic/kernel/drivers/crypto/padlock-aes.ko): No such device
```

> it is an indication that the system does not have a hardware cryptographic device (source: Ubuntu Bug #206129)
>
> The workaround is to add the following lines (using your favourite editor) to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/aliases and re-run the modprobe commands for the sha256 and aes kernel modules:

```
alias sha256 sha256_generic
alias aes aes_generic
```

> When utilising Gnome to mount the encrypted filesystems, it is not required to manually load the kernel modules.

See also : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/206129